# Finder randomly changes language in sidebar favourites

Tags: macos, finder

I have a pretty weird problem.
I have an iMac and have just had my old HDD replaced with an SSD. The old HDD is now in my optical drive's slot.

I have a clean installation of El Captain on my SSD. Unfortunately, the guys who swapped the drives for me installed El Captain in Polish. Now I changed the OS language to English as I'm more used to it, and [this](https://gyazo.com/42d38fdd746efd40bb19996015136537) is what my Finder does.

I still have an old OS installed on the other disk, which is not formatted yet. I thought that it might be by some miracle conflicting with the new installation, but Finder does this even after unmounting the old HDD.

I have absolutely no idea what to do with this, and it gets very annoying.

Has anyone had this problem before? Uncle Google brings no answers on this one :|

Comment: This is not a programming question, and would be better off asked on a site related to using/configuring OS X.

Comment: Your best guess is at http://superuser.com ... look for tags `osx` and `finder`

Comment: you guys are right. thx.